# OleVariant to TStringList

Tags: delphi

I am sending to my server using a COM+, a TStringLIst inside a parameter of type OleVariant.
Assigning it was not a problem. But, on the server, I want to convert back to TStringList.
What would be the most correct way to do this?

Client:

```
MetodClient(StringList.Text, OutParam);
```

Server:

```
function MetodServer(InputParams: OleVariant; var OutputParams: OleVariant): OleVariant;
var
  MyList: TStringList;
begin
  MyList:= TStringList.Create;
  MyList.add(InputParams);
```

The way I do it, the entire TStringList is added at index 0

Comment: Same way you did in sending it - use text.  `MyList.Text := InputParams;`

Comment: Personally, I would have stored the `TStringList` contents as an array of strings in the `OleVariant`, not as a single string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You mean, iterate the `TStringList` and in each iteration add the item to the `OleVariant` converted into Array of Variant?

Comment: @jmontegrosso An array of strings, not an array of variants.  An OLE variant can hold a SAFEARRAY of BSTR elements. But essentially yes, iterate the `TStringList` to create the array, and then iterate the array to re-fill the `TStringList`.

Comment: Passing an array of strings would certainly be less fragile. Using text has issues if any strings in the list already contain line ends as they end up getting broken up into multiple list entries.

Comment: @Brian you can mitigate that by using `CommaText`/`DelimitedText` instead of `Text`.